# Can I cheat to unlock the Binding of Isaac's achievements?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I am currently playing Binding of Isaac on my PS4. But since I just bought a new PC, I would like to switch to the PC version.

I've already spent a couple of hours playing on the PS4 and achieved all 178 achievements that are available before the DLCs. If I now start on my PC, all achievements will be gone, and some will be even harder to get (e.g. Godhead). Is it possible to use the Debug Console to cheat the achievements I already earned on my PS4?

If the Debug Console does not work, is there a way to get the achievments much more easily? That way I would just buy the vanilla Binding of Isaac, get all achiements again and buy the DLCs afterwards. Is there something like an "immortal" cheat?

Comment: It's worth noting that using programs like SAM to unlock achievements is frowned upon by achievement tracking websites (such as astats.nl) and will mark them as not counting on their trackers.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Nzall's answer a bit...

Once you've unlocked the achievements you want to by using the Steam Achievement Manager, you can then sync those achievements back to the game itself by pressing Alt-F2 on the stats page. This way, all the achievements that you've unlocked through Steam will also become unlocked in the game itself, which in turn will allow you access to those items/characters/levels/etc.

Source: [Binding of Isaac Rebirth Wiki](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Achievements#Notes)

Comment: ALT + F2 unlock my progress, but only characters. Not poster notes or items and trinckets

Answer (score 1):

There is a software called Steam Achievement Manager that can unlock achievements for any game. I haven't tried it myself yet, and it doesn't unlock achievements that are handled server-side, but it might work for your goal:

It can be found at https://github.com/gibbed/SteamAchievementManager/releases

Standard disclaimer: I am not responsible for any negative effects you may potentially experience from using this software. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a save file with 100% completion at https://savegame.pro/pc-the-binding-of-isaac-repentance-savegame/

Comment: I don't think this kind of answer is accepted here. Anyway that save file is for Repentance, OP is asking for the base game.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe, just suggesting, you can use Cheat Engine and make your runs easier until you get all of your achievements back in PC.